# multiple choice field doesn't show queryset in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am attempting to create a multiple choice field populated by a queryset.

My form looks like this:

```
class GroupLocationForm(forms.Form):
    groups_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, 
                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, customer_id, group_id):
        super(GroupLocationForm, self).__init__()
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)

        self.fields['groups_field'].queryset = Group.objects.filter(location__customer = customer).distinct()
```

Nothing shows up in terms of choices in my form.  If I add:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
                  (1,'choice 1'),
)

groups_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, 
                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

The choice shows up without any problems.

Why is my queryset not being assigned to the widget?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MultipleChoiceField` doesn't accept a `queryset` argument, but it does accept `choices`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

[ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) accepts a queryset.